# JavaScript replace() uppercase or lowercase

Tags: javascript, replace

I want to use this function but preserving the uppercase or lowercase so for example having something like

```
var value = 'Replace a string';

var search = 'replace';

value.replace(search, "<span style='font-weight: bold'>"+search+'<span>');
```

And the output of value be:

**Replace** a string

Comment: This should be the correct answer: [value = value.replace(new RegExp(search,"gi"), '...$&...');](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19252324/2816279)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you're leaving the word itself as-is, you can use a simple regex:

```
var value = 'Replace a string';
var search = /replace/i;
value = value.replace(search, "<span style='font-weight: bold'>$&</span>");
```

The `$&` indicates the matched pattern.

Comment: Thanks a lot it's working i still have to wait a few minutes and i'll accept yours. I just have a little issue left replace it's in fact a var so how i do this:
var search = /'+my_var+'/i; (this is not working)

Comment: got it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-pass-a-variable-to-a-regular-expression-javascript :D perfect thanks again

Answer (score 7):

Make `search` a regular expression and catch the case insensitive "replace" in a group:

```
var search = /(replace)/i;
```

Then, replace the word with the group, inside your `<span>` tag:

```
value.replace(search, '<span style="font-weight: bold">$1<span>');
```