# JavaScript replace lowercase uppercase

Tags: javascript, replace, uppercase, lowercase

I want to replace something (variable -> I call it "x" here) in a text (variable) with 'string'+x+'string'.

My code:

```
new_content = content.replace(new RegExp(x,"gi"),'string'+x+'string');
```

So I want to replace upper and lowercase x and the x in `'string'+x+'string'`should be lowercase if the search `x`is lowercase as well. And the same thing for uppercase.

Is there a way like `$1` for this situation?

Comment: Does using `$1` not work for some reason? You specification of when exactly you want the replacement to be uppercase or lowercase isn't very clear.

Comment: $1 is not working because I don't have sth. like `(.*)`

Comment: `'string$&string'` is the solution, no need of parenthesis `;)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `$&` in the replacement string to insert the matched string:

```
new_content = content.replace(new RegExp(x,"gi"), 'string$&string');
```